# Why should one choose the maximum as reference for power-to-decibel conversion?

Tags: spectrogram, stft

I have seen that one converts the amplitude to decibels through:
$\text{dB(S)}=10 \text{log}_{10} \big(\text{S/ref}\big)$, where $\text{S}$ is the output of a STFT and ref the reference value for the logarithmic scale, i.e. the value that should be mapped to decibel, right?

However, I've seen implementations with $\text{ref = max(S)}$
and I do not understand why. Can someone clarify on that?

Comment: Some people like the maximum value to be 0 dB. It's just a preference, that's all.

Comment: But what's the point of this? Seems very counter-intuitive to me

Comment: "I have seen" -- please provide a reference.  *Where* have you seen this?  Context matters.

Comment: @tmueller, In audio, 0 dB is practically the norm. It allows you to compare different tracks  in terms of their amplitude/power easily (and you can also estimate the amplitude of a single track easily).

Answer (score 1):

dB is a power ratio, so when we see units in dB we are seeing units on a relative scale. The reason that a 0 dB reference is so common is because this is simply normalizing the number scale to 1. $10Log(1) = 0$ dB

This is similar to using 100% (1) instead of absolute numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not generally true. As mentioned in the comments, it may be a preference to take the maximum of the signal as 0 dB. But a counter example is the power measurements in wireless systems. We define dBm as:
$P [dBm] = 10log(P / 1 (mW))$

We may have actual powers as high as 30 dBm. The voice ratings are other counter examples. There is no single reference for conversion from linear scale to logarithmic scale.